# Create suitable DataFrame for plotly plot

Tags: pandas, dataframe, plotly

I have the following dict:

```
dic = {(1, 1, 1): 0.0, (1, 1, 2): 0.0, (1, 1, 3): 1.0, (1, 2, 1): 0.0, (1, 2, 2): 1.0, (1, 2, 3): 0.0, (1, 3, 1): 0.0, (1, 3, 2): 0.0, (1, 3, 3): 0.0, (1, 4, 1): 0.0, (1, 4, 2): 1.0, (1, 4, 3): 0.0, (1, 5, 1): 1.0, (1, 5, 2): 0.0, (1, 5, 3): 0.0, (1, 6, 1): 0.0, (1, 6, 2): 1.0, (1, 6, 3): 0.0, (1, 7, 1): 0.0, (1, 7, 2): 1.0, (1, 7, 3): 0.0, (2, 1, 1): 1.0, (2, 1, 2): 0.0, (2, 1, 3): 0.0, (2, 2, 1): 1.0, (2, 2, 2): 0.0, (2, 2, 3): 0.0, (2, 3, 1): 1.0, (2, 3, 2): 0.0, (2, 3, 3): 0.0, (2, 4, 1): 0.0, (2, 4, 2): 0.0, (2, 4, 3): 0.0, (2, 5, 1): 1.0, (2, 5, 2): 0.0, (2, 5, 3): 0.0, (2, 6, 1): 0.0, (2, 6, 2): 0.0, (2, 6, 3): 1.0, (2, 7, 1): 0.0, (2, 7, 2): 1.0, (2, 7, 3): 0.0, (3, 1, 1): 1.0, (3, 1, 2): 0.0, (3, 1, 3): 0.0, (3, 2, 1): 0.0, (3, 2, 2): 1.0, (3, 2, 3): 0.0, (3, 3, 1): 0.0, (3, 3, 2): 0.0, (3, 3, 3): 0.0, (3, 4, 1): 1.0, (3, 4, 2): 0.0, (3, 4, 3): 0.0, (3, 5, 1): 1.0, (3, 5, 2): 0.0, (3, 5, 3): 0.0, (3, 6, 1): 1.0, (3, 6, 2): 0.0, (3, 6, 3): 0.0, (3, 7, 1): 0.0, (3, 7, 2): 1.0, (3, 7, 3): 0.0}
```

would like to have a pandas DataFrame from it. The dict is structured as follows.The first number in the brackets is the person index i (there should be this many lines).The second number is the tag index t. There should be this many columns. The third number is the shift being worked. A 1 after the colon indicates that a shift was worked, a that it was not worked. If all shifts on a day have passed without a 1 after the colon, then a 0 should represent the combination of i and t, otherwise the shift worked. According to the dict above, the pandas DataFrame should look like this.

```
DataFrame:     1  2  3  4  5  6  7 
1              3  2  0  2  1  2  2 
2              1  1  1  0  1  3  2 
3              1  2  0  1  1  3  2
```

I then want to use it with this function.

```
def visualize(data):
    title_str = f'Title'
    fig = px.imshow(data[[str(i) for i in range(1, 8)]], color_continuous_scale=["red", "orange", "blue", 'black'],
                    title=title_str,)
    fig.update(data=[{'hovertemplate': "Day: %{x}<br>"
                                       "Physician: %{y}<br>",
                      }])
    colorbar = dict(thickness=25,
                     tickvals=[0, 1, 2, 3],
                     ticktext=['Morning', 'Noon', 'Evening', 'Off'])
    fig.update(layout_coloraxis_showscale=True, layout_coloraxis_colorbar=colorbar)
    fig.show()
 
    return fig
```

Answer (score 3):

Convert to Series to have a MultiIndex with person/tag/shift, then select the rows with value == 1, finally, move the shift to column with [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and [`unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html):

```
out = (pd.Series(dic).loc[lambda s: s==1]
         .reset_index(-1)['level_2'].unstack(fill_value=0)
      )
```

Variant with [`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table):

```
out = (pd
   .Series(dic, name='worked').reset_index()
   .query('worked == 1')
   .pivot_table(index='level_0', columns='level_1', values='level_2', fill_value=0)
   .convert_dtypes().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  3  2  0  2  1  2  2
2  1  1  1  0  1  3  2
3  1  2  0  1  1  1  2
```

If you can have all-zeros rows or columns and want to preserve them, you need an additional [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
s = pd.Series(dic)

out = (s.loc[lambda s: s==1]
        .reset_index(-1)['level_2'].unstack(fill_value=0)
        .reindex(index=s.index.get_level_values(0).unique(),
                 columns=s.index.get_level_values(1).unique(),
                 fill_value=0
                ) 
      )
```

Example output (if your had `{(2, 3, 1): 0.0}` in place of `{(2, 3, 1): 1.0}`):

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  3  2  0  2  1  2  2
2  1  1  0  0  1  3  2
3  1  2  0  1  1  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it doesnt work with the plot code. It yields this error. KeyError: "None of [Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]" Any idea on how i can fix that?

Comment: @nflgreaternba in your function you slice with `[str(i) for i in range(1, 8)]` but your indices are actually integers. Try to slice with `list(range(1, 8))` instead

Answer (score 1):

This won't be very efficient if your data set is large, but it works:

```
# get maximum indices for person and tag
max_person = max(key[0] for key in dic.keys())
max_tag = max(key[1] for key in dic.keys())

# initialize empty df
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(1, max_person + 1), columns=range(1, max_tag + 1))

# populate df using `dic`
for (person, tag, shift), value in dic.items():
    if value == 1.0:
        df.loc[person, tag] = shift

# fill missing values with 0
df = df.fillna(0)
```

```
   1  2  3  4  5  6  7
1  3  2  0  2  1  2  2
2  1  1  1  0  1  3  2
3  1  2  0  1  1  1  2
```

Comment: Thanks. Sadly it doesnt work with the plot code. It yields this error. KeyError: "None of [Index(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"
How can i fix that?

Comment: @nflgreaternba replace `data[[str(i) for i in range(1, 8)]]` with `data`